# Sum across rows but only the cells that meet a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**Sample data:**

```
df <- tibble(x = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4),
             y = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
             z = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
df
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.1   0.1   0.1
2   0.2   0.1   0.2
3   0.3   0.2   0.2
4   0.4   0.3   0.2
```

I want to sum across rows and I want to only add up the "cells" that meet a certain logical condition. In this example, I want to add up, rowwise, only cells that contain a equal to or greater than a specified threshold.

**Desired Output**

```
threshold <- 0.15
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      x     y     z cond_sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1   0.1   0.1   0.1      0  
2   0.2   0.1   0.2      0.4
3   0.3   0.2   0.2      0.7
4   0.4   0.3   0.2      0.9
```

**Pseudo-code**

This is the wrangling idea I have in mind.

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(cond_sum = sum(c_across(where(~ "cell" >= threshold))))
```

Tidy solutions appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An efficient option is replace the values that are below the threshold to NA and make use of `na.rm` in `rowSums` instead of `rowwise/c_across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(cond_sum = rowSums(replace(., . < threshold, NA), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#      x     y     z cond_sum
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1   0.1   0.1   0.1      0  
#2   0.2   0.1   0.2      0.4
#3   0.3   0.2   0.2      0.7
#4   0.4   0.3   0.2      0.9
```

---

Or with `c_across`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(cond_sum = {val <- c_across(everything())
                     sum(val[val >= threshold])}) %>%
  ungroup
```

---

Or `base R`

```
df$cond_sum <- rowSums(replace(df, df < threshold, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond_sum = pmap_dbl(across(x:z), ~ sum(c(...)[c(...) > threshold])))

      x     y     z cond_sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1   0.1   0.1   0.1      0  
2   0.2   0.1   0.2      0.4
3   0.3   0.2   0.2      0.7
4   0.4   0.3   0.2      0.9
```

Or just using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond_sum = Reduce(`+`, across(x:z) * (across(x:z) > threshold)))
```